# CSS simplify giant > list?

Tags: css

I have a bunch of CSS code, and I want to try and simplify it but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. By simplify it I'd like to have maybe 1 or two "statements" rather then like 15. For browser support I only need latest Chrome. Is there anyway to do it?

```
body.app .tree ul li li {
    padding-left: 25px;
}

body.app .tree ul li li li {
    padding-left: 50px;
}

body.app .tree ul li li li li {
    padding-left: 75px;
}

body.app .tree ul li li li li li {
    padding-left: 100px;
}

body.app .tree ul li li li li li li {
    padding-left: 125px;
}

body.app .tree ul li li li li li li li {
    padding-left: 150px;
}

body.app .tree ul li li li li li li li li li {
    padding-left: 175px;
}

body.app .tree ul li li li li li li li li li li {
    padding-left: 200px;
}
```

Comment: `li > li` matches invalid HTML.

Comment: Opps fixed lol that was my bad.

Comment: You shouldn't need that at all; each successive `li` element should add its own padding from your first rule.

Comment: @SLaks I thought that too, but `<li>` uses `display:list-item` which ignores any padding or margin. Actually the padding should be added to `<ul>` elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `display` type of `<li>` ignore any padding or margin because you're supposed to create new sub-levels in your list using `<ul>` inside `<li>`.

```css
li > ul {
  padding-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    Item 1
    <ul>
      <li>
        Item 1-1
      </li>
      <li>
        Item 1-2
        <ul>
          <li>
            Item 1-2-1
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    Item 2
  </li>
  <ul>
```

You can define a custom padding for each sub-level, like `25px` as you wanted:

```
li > ul
{
    padding-left:25px;
}
```